# NetCDF variable comes without crs and extent

Tags: r, netcdf, extent

I am very new to netCDF data and spatial data in general, so sorry if my question is not very bright.

I am using R, and my goal is to extract a raster out of temperature data that can be [downloaded here](http://vesg.ipsl.upmc.fr/thredds/fileServer/cmip6/ScenarioMIP/IPSL/IPSL-CM6A-LR/ssp126/r1i1p1f1/Amon/tas/gr/v20190121/tas_Amon_IPSL-CM6A-LR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gr_201501-210012.nc).

I run the following code:

```
pathname <- ".../"

filename <- "tas_Amon_IPSL-CM6A-LR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gr_201501-210012"
file <- nc_open(paste0(pathname, filename, '.nc'))

# get longitude, latitude and time
lon <- ncvar_get(file,"lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(file,"lat")

# get time
time <- ncvar_get(file,"time")
nt <- dim(time)
tunits <- ncatt_get(file,"time","units")

# get the variable and convert as rasterBrick
thevar <- ncvar_get(file, 'tas')
thevar_b <- brick(thevar)

# take a slice of it and plot as image
thevar_slice <- thevar[,,1]
image(lon,lat,thevar_slicev, col=rev(brewer.pal(10,"RdBu")))
```

The problem is that I do not manage to extract the crs and extent of the netCDF data with `brick()`. The `image()` plots the data correctly, but when I use `proj4string` to project to `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0`, then lon and lat are swapped, and the grids are stretched.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi Lucile.  Welcome to SO. I think for GIS or remote sensing question especially around data problems [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is a better forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is fine.

```
r <- brick("tas_Amon_IPSL-CM6A-LR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gr_201501-210012.nc")
plot(r$X2015.01.16)

#r$X2015.01.16
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  1032  bands)
dimensions  : 143, 144, 20592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2.5, 1.267606  (x, y)
extent      : -1.25, 358.75, -90.6338, 90.6338  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:....
names       : X2015.01.16 
z-value     : 2015-01-16 
zvar        : tas
```

**If you are using NOAA POD:** The longitude of the point written as either positive 0 to 360W or positive 0 to 180W and negative 0 to 180E. Easy to convert but totally not an R question.

Comment: thank you very much, again I'm very sorry this was so trivial

Comment: No worries, we all have been played with the tricky form of spatial data one way or another. Please consider accepting this response if it was the correct answer to your question.